# How to append hash value when key is same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Here is member and member_email details:

```
- @members.each do |member|
    - member.member_emails.each do |member_email|
        - email_hash = { member.id.to_s => { member_email.kind => member_email.email } }
```

How to append the hash when there is already key exists?
Getting the results for the email_hash is:

```
 {"6"=>{"personal"=>"abc@gmail.com"}}
 {"4"=>{"work"=>"def@yahoo.com"}}
 {"4"=>{"personal"=>"xyz@gmail.com"}}
```

Expected result is:

```
 {"6"=>{"personal"=>"abc@gmail.com"}}
 {"4"=>{"work"=>"def@yahoo.com", "personal"=>"xyz@gmail.com"}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your hash examples are not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do (don't know the context) but right now, you are looping through `member.member_emails` and creating a new hash for **each** email. Assuming that what you want to create just one hash for each user, you could do something like:

```
- @members.each do |member|
    - email_hash = {}
    - member.member_emails.each do |member_email|
        - email_hash[member_email.kind] = member_email.email
    - user_hash = { member.id.to_s => email_hash }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

Assuming value is a hash.

```
def add_or_append(hash, key, value)
   if hash[key]
    hash[key].merge(value)
   else
    hash[key] = value
   end
end
```

If value is a string:

```
def add_or_append(hash, key, value)
   if hash[key]
    hash[key] << ", #{value}"
   else
    hash[key] = value
   end
end
```